# Replace first space on each line by a tab

Tags: bash, macos, perl, sed, whitespace

On macOS command line, how to replace first occurrence of a space by a tab, on each line of a file?

Examples of available tools on macOS: **bash 3.2**, **BSD sed**, awk, tr, perl 5, python 2.7, swift 4, etc.

I tried:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) /\1\t/' filename
```

But instead of a tab, I get the character 't'.

Comment: Escaping the `\t` with an additional backslash?

Comment: @tobiasegli_te then I get a '\' and a 't', but no tab

Comment: In bash, try `sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) /\1'$'\t''/' filename`

Comment: @Cœur: Or more simply just do `sed -e "s/ /$(printf '\t')/" <file`

Comment: with perl, `perl -pe 's/ /\t/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good answers were posted in the comments. Here are some credits:

Thanks Leon and Inian for this solution:

```
sed 's/ /'$'\t''/' filename
```

Thanks Sundeep for this solution:

```
perl -pe 's/ /\t/' filename
```

Thanks Sundeep for finding the duplicate question, which gives this literal solution where the replacement string is a tab obtained in bash through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> (note: copy-pasting it from Stack Overflow will *not* work):

```
sed 's/ / /' filename
```